# JSF Primefaces application doesn't render properly on upgraded WildFly 18

Tags: jsf, primefaces, wildfly, omnifaces

I upgraded my server in Eclipse from WildFly v10.x to WildFly 18.0.0 Final and now one of my JSF/Primefaces applications doesn't render properly after updating the view.  On initial page load the view looks fine but if I select some filters (Primeface dropdowns, checkboxes, etc..) and click a command button to refresh the view (AJAX), it renders as if Primefaces is no longer available. See screenshots

Initial View Renders Fine:
[image]

After View Is Updated:
[image]

The error while debugging in Chrome:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'cw' of undefined or null reference
```

.

```
$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Growl','widget_growl',{id:'growl',sticky:false,life:5000,escape:true,msgs:[]});});
```

Not sure why the application is now not working after just upgrading WildFly.

Comment: Any network errors in the browser (network tab in developer tools)?  Running in https? Using http/2 by chance?

Comment: @Kukeltje, no, there are zero network errors.

Comment: maybe try wildfly 18.0.1. I had some other issues with 18.0.0 but 18.0.1 now works for me good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by replacing `@all` on the `p:commandButton` with a more specific target

```
<p:commandButton action="#{...}" update="@all" />
<p:commandButton action="#{...}" update=":tripFormId:dataTableId" />
```

I realized after seeing this in the Chrome console debugger

> jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=7.0:2 [Deprecation] Synchronous
>   XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its
>   detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check
>   https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.